# Dynamically rename header to 1,2,3,4,5

Tags: alteryx

Im trying to remame the columns in the table below with ascending integers. The dates will change week on week, so I need a way to dynamically rename in alteryx, is there a way of doing this with the dynamic rename tool? or another method perhaps?

[image]

To be turned into:

| Week Start | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week | 46 | 47 | 47 | 48 | 49 |

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use a combination of the Transform tools and a Record ID.  Use the Transpose tool with the 'Week Start' as your "Key column" then use the Summarize and group by the new Name field to get a list of all your dates and sort the dates in ascending order.

Add a Record ID after to give each date an ID.  Join this back to the original Transpose and then Cross Tab to get the output you want.

See screenshot in link below.

[AlteryxChangeColumnnames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtCdW.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).